# How can I prevent positioned block images from sliding off the page?

Tags: html, css

When I resize the window too small, the image slides off the left of the page. There is no way to even scroll over to it. What can I do to prevent the image from sliding off the page? The problem is absolute divs but I don't know how to get it to work without them.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
}
.chart {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="chart">
  <img src="Resources/chart.png" width="432" height="256" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -128px; right: 0;"/>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

1: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?11b1fcb689.png>http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.11b1fcb689.png

Answer (score 1):

Position it with:

```
.chart {position: relative; }
```

`position:absolute;` takes it out of the document's flow, so it's not accounted for with scrollbars. `position: relative;` keeps the element in the flow, so you can still scroll to it.

### Edit

---

In response to Michael's comment:

> I'd like it to be centered vertically. Is it possible with relative positioning?

Yes, it is. And it involves a little jiggery-pokery, but I'm using FF3.0.11/Ubuntu 8.04, so the weirdness may be platform dependant.

First define the top-left corner of the positioned element:

```
.chart {position: relative;
        width: 50%;
        left: 50%; /* 50% works for left-position, but wouldn't for 'top' */
        margin: 25% 0 0 -25%;
}
```

To explain the margins:

I tried initially to use the same positioning I'd use with `position: absolute;` (`top: 50%; left: 50%;`), but that didn't work. I'm not sure why, exactly, though I suspect that it's related to how the height of the percentage is calculated. Still, trial and error (and this is why I noted my browser/platform above) found that 25% seemed to place the origin (top left corner of `.chart`) in the right place.

The 25% then represents *only* my *best-guess of* vertically-centre. The -25% is easier to understand, it's the usual 'horizontal-center minus half the element-width' thing. Although you could maybe more-easily just use `width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;` to achieve the same thing.

I don't understand why positioning with the usual `top: 50%` didn't work, but I am using a css-reset stylesheet (specifically Eric Meyer's 'reset reloaded' stylesheet, found here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/)

It's worth noting that the page appears consistently-with-Firefox in Midori (which, I think, uses the Webkit rendering engine), and I'll be uploading the demo page shortly (to: http://www.davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/rel-pos-centre.html) for public <del>ridicule</del> review for differences.

And also, if anyone could help out and explain the weirdness in having to vertical-position with margins rather than `top: xx` that'd be appreciated.

Comment: I'd like it to be centered vertically. Is it possible with relative positioning?

Comment: On a scrolling page? Or a 1 page page?

Comment: @Eric: I'm sorry, what..? O.o